# Finding the labels in panda Dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I have a large number of png files where each filename is a unique ID with a corresponding data in a large pandas Dataframe. I can find the filenames by os.list and then try to find the corresponfin "ind = df['image_id']==name". However, this is a very slow process. Is there a more efficient approach?

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    name = file.split(".")[0]
    index = df['image_id']==name
    print(df.loc[index].values[0][1])
```

Comment: Your [mre] should include a minimal example of the DataFrame. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe make the filename list into a set then use the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method to get all the indices at once.  It is a little hard as you didn't give us an example DataFrame to work with.

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path)
names = set((path.split('.')[0] for path in files))
mask = df['image_id'].isin(names)
```